# Email ID , Subject and Message not setting in android Send Intent

Tags: java, android, email, android-intent

I am sending email using intent but the subject and message body is not being set.

```
    Intent sendMail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendMail.setType("*/*");
    sendMail.setType("message/html");
    sendMail.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");
    sendMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL , email);
    sendMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT , subject);
    sendMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT , message);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendMail , "Choose an Email Client"));
```

Comment: Do you have Gmail app on your device/emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced this problem. Be clear that those `string` values are not null. You could also use `ACTION.SENDTO`. Use the below code; it worked for me.

```
    Intent sendMail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    sendMail.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{email});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    intent.setSelector( sendMail );
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an Email Client"));
```